# im having a PANIC when running some assembly in bochs

Tags: c, nasm, emulation, bootloader, bochs

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxcIH.png) showcase the error im getting when running the command "bochs" in the bootDIr directory where my assembly file , the image ,the binary and the script are at , the tutorial i watched was using ubuntu while im using kali,i dont think that was relevant but i would love your help

the goal is to show the "Hello" String when booting (+some messages generated by the emulator)
here is the nasm code:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

start :  
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

PrintMessage :
    mov ah,0x13
    mov al, 1
    mov bx,0xa
    xor dx,dx
    mov bp, Message
    mov cx, MessageLen
    int 0x10

End :
    hlt
    jmp End

Message : db "Hello"
MessageLen : equ $-Message

times (0x1be -($-$$)) db 0

    db 80h
    db 0,2,0
    db 0f0h
    db 0ffh,0ffh,0ffh
    dd 1
    dd (20*16*63 - 1 )
    

    times (16*3) db 0

    db 0x55
    db 0xaa
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with your code and everything to do with the way Bochs is set up. It's complaining that it can't find any way to display stuff on the screen.

Comment: how can i fix it ?